# div keeps moving to the left on resize

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css

I am trying to make a website using NextJS and tailwindcss. But the div keeps shifting towards the left whenever the browser window is been resized.

Here is how it looks on resize but the text should be centered

[image: On resize]

Here is how it looks on desktop

[image: desktop]

```
import { IoIosArrowForward } from "react-icons/io";
import Link from "next/link";

const About = () => {
  return (
    <div className="font-inter py-4 my-16 flex justify-center items-center flex-col"
      id="about">
      <p className="text-6xl font-bold text-gray-700 text-center">
        Hey, I&apos;m Anurag
      </p>
      <p className="text-2xl text-gray-600 text-center my-8">
        Hey there, I&apos;m a Frontend Developer based in India. <br />
        I&apos;m mainly focused on Frontend Development, and I also write blogs
        and design sometimes. <br />
        Apart from coding, I love listening to music!
      </p>
      <p className="flex justify-center">
        <Link href="https://github.com/kr-anurag" passHref>
          <a className="text-xl w-72 text-white font-medium px-4 py-3 rounded-full flex items-center justify-center bg-gradient-to-r from-[#12c2e9] via-[#c471ed] to-[#f64f59] shadow-xl hover:bg-gradient-to-l duration-100"
            aria-label="github-account"
            target="blank">
            Checkout my Github
            <IoIosArrowForward />
          </a>
        </Link>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default About;
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding one tailwind class would solve the issue.
Add `w-full` to **#about** div. [Here](https://windicss.org/play.html?html=DwEwlgbgBAxgNgQwM5ILwCIECMD2BXAF3SjBA23yID4AoKKYAB1kRQwDsEBbAU3SoASPAJ4AaKAEkA5FygBBdngBOCAObAA9I1r0mLZGnQgeSGPzr0oQ4VAIALHkp7jpshFABiSnOwI92IFAAIjwQPHA4jI5QWMg8gWDskgFgCAB0wFhKOpauUFwIiXA2AGY4MHhI8VA%2Bnt6%2B-oEhYRGMvL7iCAGSUAhwSDhQAO5KYH4xEapIFvRdgcZIYKpJA7wEYLxIGVlUcowISgRQJd6yMDjg7KouUBFht2BIfuyJqraDXJVgMACEFpraf7MeAGDAlOA8AAeUAAVpV1iVhABaGD%2BPxKEh%2BLhIFFoxzmSwMdwgtjoLAEdjEA6pJGILDhDCqMZ2PBYJEIGDnPC%2BYgEA6qHgEDBYRDsADWBMJUAAwg4YGLKPkbABxZmsmaWYBICBvEmGIZIgBsUDsRqgT28Yp4SKGdjGfGOYDgcA4PgdFpwVowFSUTl80pwESUxAgYB4QwAQjhIRgAAxQeMAJgALFAU8RIVw4OxDHYCARGAAuDQaIZltJDADMaRwSlUGkTsabGm1qn4TAQ9nNBEt1rgiR4MAQjAw3m5IGIHqttIHMJwiVH%2BACk57nutQ1I9gwieIZHQAFkAJxQACscAA7FBz0jL%2Bf21pO3YqJpWzldBoEDkAbRNOAIFQgA&css=HQQwRg9grgLgBAbwFBzgARAB0wGwJ5wBmOApgB5wBWUAzjAJaF4C0AxiQHYwkBOc93ALY02nbn2Lk2EHCjgBIQhC7MaIDjTiYWAFjiCWARgBscAOZZmentA4ATEneaC7WslbgB3ZoSg4ccJA8DjxyqDQAFiB2EN44ZoFmzDA8UCTMZjwgLABMAAx5cHYgPADWAFxgSSlpGVksAOwFRSUVkdGxddnMxgUA3EgAvkjAHCCCJIhyGNj4cNxkMMw5ZAEu5QtLxqtEykuQOK6bXY3NxWUb5EuZ3fmFx%2BxcvAPDwA40rFOoM7gEx2AgGiTVaXRbMHbHG4sXqFc4VSH1ZgAZmaDzEvCGIzAMA4X3QWF%2BYXmV3BAWOngiAkmShUEzs9CggjcHm0yzgNig9kcPj8slQqEkFCpwlETz41DojBYj3ERKqXXpYmSEGYEhsgmYAG0AMSGHKsHIkACcAF04AA3eggLXa1g6BqGRxmmAqnWEYw6QgAVlNRPaMW8OwiEHNvEqSRuipULuYATsUCyDGUzEMXryLyQQA), is the sample of your code. Please check it out.

It works!

Comment: I have tried it already, It didn't work

Comment: Here is the github repo for the entire code: https://github.com/Kira272921/portfolio-template

Comment: @Kira unfortunately, this link un-available

Comment: Hey i have solved the issue, I had just fork
Thanks tho :D